# How to request access for Microsoft Graph Explorer?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to add Group.ReadAll and Group.ReadWrite.All permissions to Graph Explorer. When I open the permissions and add them I'm told I need admin approval, although these specific permissions do not require approval. I want to add these permissions without taking away existing admin approvals. How do I do this? The pop up does not have an option to ask that and 2018's [solution](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer-v4/issues/615) is not working for me! I just cannot move on to permissions request page or anything similar. I do not find Graph Explorer in AAD apps or anywhere. How can I request admin to provide these permissions to Graph Explorer to my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Microsoft Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
when you query related to Groups(https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups), you will get below error which says you don't have access to

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-08-08T11:36:28",
        "request-id": "b3bd3b88-a1b2-4a57-9e60-c495daf7f528"
    }
```

In order to have the access, org admin can provide the access by following the below steps:

1. Login to Graph Explorer.
2. Select Permission.
3. **Group.Read.All** and **Group.ReadWrite.All** (Below is the screenshot)

[image: Permission]

**Admin will get below screen**

[image: Admin Screen]

Now any users from the org can do group related operations.